# Animating div with centered content- show top one gradually from right to left

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an animation where a div "changes its color" and so do the contents in it. 
Different stages in the animations are shown below.
The div you see in the images look like this in the view. I names the class row1 because when I was using just "row" I realized bootstrap might be messing up with something.

```
<div class="row1 facebook">
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="image"></div>
        <label class="text">facebook</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying to use 2 divs where the bottom one is the one with the white background and the top one is the one with the color, have it be 0px of with in the beginning and then increase the width gradually which having overflow-x:hidden, but I've been encountering problems because I'm trying to keep the contents centered so the content kept moving while resizing.

[image: stage 1]

[image: stage 2]

[image: stage 3]

[image: 2 colors of logo and text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6tneqpa5/2/

**Explanation:** I use jquery to set width of inner div and position it absolute. While move it's parent div using only css this causes it to clip it's child element.

I added more animation which is not what you asked for, but i guess this deserved it.

Code:

Js

```
$('.main').width($('.out').width());
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.main').width($('.out').width());
});
```

css

```
* {    padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.out {
    height: 180px;
    font-family: "Helvetica";
    font-size: 0;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bg, .top {
    font-size: 1rem;
    height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 170px;
}
.bg {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 59%,#ededed 100%);
}

.top, .main {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; top: 0; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.top {
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
.out:hover .top {
    width: 100%;
}
.main {
    background-color: #f53f39;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: add relevant prefixes for other browsers for transition property, right now transition only works in chrome or webkit browsers.

Comment: I'm looking at your solution now, looks promising, thank you!

Comment: 2nd version of your fiddle is what I needed, thank you so much for your help and effort!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the main container,
the animated background,
then the logo.

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="animated">
     </div>
     <div id="logo">
     </div>
</div>
```

**[This is a link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wesg2yfz/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for the effort but it's not quite what I needed. Notice in the images how the animating container also has the logo and text but in different colors.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="hover">
        <div>Facebook</div>
    </div>
    <div class="default">
        <div>Facebook</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Once the user enters the container we animate the **.default** element setting his **width** equal to 0 (zero) using jQuery.

**JS:**

```
$(".container").on({
    "mouseenter" : function() {
        $(".default", this).stop().animate({
        width: "0%",
        }, 700, function() {
            $("div", this).hide();
        });
    },
    "mouseleave" : function() {
        $(".default div", this).show();
        $(".default", this).stop().animate({
        width: "100%",
        }, 700);
    }
});
```

The **DIVs** inside the **.default** and **.hover** should be positioned based on their parents size, setting their **position** attribute to **absolute**. This way, even if their parent width is changing, the element will keep his position.

For more details you can check this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dim13i/voarfg23/5/) where you will see how I define the size of each element and its position using CSS and jQuery.